# Uses for Old bread dough

Tags: culinary-uses, dough, yeast, fermentation, bread

I found some old bread dough that I had left, sealed in tupperware, in my fridge. It has a powerful fermented smell, but doesn't appear to be moldy or otherwise bad. Is there any use for this fermented dough? The dough was water, salt, oil, sugar, and yeast and has been hanging in my fridge for about 2 months.

Comment: edited question to reflect comments

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mix it into new batches of artisan bread. It will give you some awesome flavor.

I doubt that sealed in the fridge it was able to pick up any interesting bacteria that would make it a sourdough starter but it would still be a more adventerous flavor than a young dough.

You could try making bread with just this dough but I would be afraid of it being too acidic and strongly flavored. I personally would just use it as a starter for other batches of bread.

Comment: On top of the bread made with all of this dough being too strong, the over proofing that has probably taken place might not give it the best texture - too bubbly (and not in a big and open crumb way) and not firm enough.

Comment: I will give this a try and see what happens!

Comment: justkt: I think the way to handle it would be to use a small amount of it sort of as a starter like a biga or poolish. You'd basically use a little of this dough in place of some of your flour, and you wouldn't add any other yeast. Then work as normal for the bread you make.

Comment: yeah, i just made some bread out of the same type of situation. it's a bit weird, but kinda good, in a funky way. definitely starter is the way to go!